# How to Load In Content with AMP?

Tags: amp-html

I try to find similar solution for ajax, but in amp I can't use it right?

This is what I would like to make ([link](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/011_jQuerySite/sample/index.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use AMP actions and events](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/) and bind the buttons [with the `on` attribute.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzEQNC33_A4&list=PLadWW12WRDFO7xMngUtJ8eZVFodje9k6o&index=5)

You need to load the content beforehand tho. If you need it loaded dynamically, you have to use `amp-list`